# C# / Filter input of a textbox and display notification balloon

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm wondering how to filter the input of a .NET textbox.

I already know that I could listen for the KeyDown event and intercept the key, but that won't filter pasted strings by a right-click menu or a CTRL+V.

I also don't wan't to completely disable the possibility of pasting of characters in the textbox. The paste action should be cancelled whenever it contains one or more invalid characters.

Finally, I'd like to display a notification balloon whenever invalid characters are either entered or pasted.

μTorrent already has this exact behavior:

[image]

How can I achieve this functionality in C# ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like a combination of [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx), [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx), [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx), and [Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx) events should work for your purposes.

Comment: What about the notification balloon?

Comment: Why the downvote?

The notification balloon isn't really that difficult as it is actually a ToolTip. Just create a ToolTip and in your validation routine just call `YourToolTip.Show("Tooltip text goes here", txtYourTextbox)` to show it, and `YourToolTip.Hide("Tooltip text goes here", txtYourTextbox)` to hide it. The balloon style is defined as a property of the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

[TextChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28VS.80%29.aspx) - Seems like a good call.

You can spawn your own baloon or ToolTip on any control you want to show a detailed feedback to the user

Comment: I tried that already. When the even is fired, it is too late: the text is already changed.